# Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) \end{document}

Tags: errors, header-footer, fancyhdr

By looking at questions with same title as mine, I unfortunately don't find answers to fix my code.
I am not too familiar with LaTex, but after reading several webpages I really can't see what I am doing wrong.

It seems as if the error message in the title appears whenever my document is taking in use the second page. Therefore I give you a full copy of my code to have the 'critical' mass of text to look at.

There sholdn't be any problems before the '\newpage' command (the last 7 lines i the code), but as I am not yet the biggest LaTex shark my preamle might be the one causing all the troubles.

Can anyone figure why I get this error message when compiling?
And what can I do to fix the problems?

So here is my total code:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[danish]{babel}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{geometry,fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{ulem} %for dobbelt understregning af resultater brug \uuline{}
    \usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}

    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \lhead{Malte Bødkergaard Nielsen, hold 9}
    \cfoot{Side \thepage\ af \pagetotal}
    \geometry{headheight=2cm}
    \setlength{\jot}{10pt}

    \title{\textbf{Analyse 0\\ Obligatorisk opgave 2\\}}
    \author{\emph{Malte Bødkergaard Nielsen} \\ \\Hold 9}
    \begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \section*{Opgave 1}
    Hyperbolsk cosinus og sinus er givet ved:
    \begin{align*}
    \cosh(x)=\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2} &&,&& \sinh(x)=\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2} && \text{for $x\in\mathbb{R}$}
    \end{align*}
    Dermed findes den afledte for $\cosh(x)$ og $\sinh(x)$ vha. sætning 4.9, der fortæller os, at hvis $f$ og $g$ er differentiable i et punkt $a$, så vi $h=f+g$ også være det. Således kan vi splitte $\cosh(x)$ og $\sinh(x)$ op i en sum af to eksponentialfunktioner, og de hyperbolske funktioners differentiabilitet afhænger dermed af eksponentialfunktionens differentiabilitet.\\
    Yderligere må vi benytte sætning 4.11 (kædereglen), der fortæller, at hvis $g_1$ er differentiabel i et punkt $a$, og hvis $g_2$ er differentiabel i et punkt $b=g_1(a)$, så vil $g_2\circ g_1$ være differentiabel i $a$.\\
    Sætningerne 4.9 og 4.11 oversættes til at gælde for funktioner, der er differentiable i alle punkter $x\in I$.\\
    Det følger af eksempel 4.5, at $\exp'(x)=\exp(x)$. Af eksemplet ses nemt, at vi kan gange enhver konstant $k_1$ på eksponentialfunktionen, og jvf. eksemplets argumentation opnå, at $(k_1\cdot\exp(x))'=k_1\cdot\exp'(x)=k_1\cdot\exp(x)$.\\
    Dermed har vi:
    \begin{align*}
    && f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot e^{x} &&,&& g(x)=g_2\circ g_1 && \text{for $x\in\mathbb{R}$}\\
    \text{hvor} && g_1(x)=-x &&,&& g_2(y)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot e^{y} && \text{for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$}
    \end{align*}
    Kædereglen giver os nu:
    \begin{align*}
    g'(x)=(g_2\circ g_1)'(x)=g_2'(g_1(x))\cdot g_1'(x)= \frac{1}{2}\cdot e^{-x}\cdot (-1)= -\frac{1}{2}\cdot e^{-x}
    \end{align*}
    For at udregne $g_1'(x)$ har vi benyttet resultatet fra eksempel 4.2, hvor det vises, at $x^{k}$ differentierer til $k\cdot x^{k-1}$. Resultatet fra dette eksempel ses at kunne ganges med en vilkårlig konstant $k_1$, således at $(k_1\cdot x^{k})'=k_1\cdot k\cdot x^{k-1}$.\\
    Med alle disse brudstykker får vi:
    \begin{align*}
    \cosh(x)=\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}=f(x)+g(x)=f(x)+(g_2\circ g_1)(x)\\
    \Rightarrow\cosh'(x)=f'(x)+g'(x)= \frac{1}{2}\cdot e^{x} + \left(-\frac{1}{2}\cdot e^{-x}\right) =\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}=\sinh(x)\\
    \text{for $x\in\mathbb{R}$}
    \end{align*}
    På samme vis får for $\sinh(x)$:
    \begin{align*}
    \sinh(x)=\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}=f(x)-g(x)=f(x)-(g_2\circ g_1)(x)\\
    \Rightarrow\sinh'(x)=f'(x)-g'(x)= \frac{1}{2}\cdot e^{x} - \left(-\frac{1}{2}\cdot e^{-x}\right) =\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}=\cosh(x)\\
    \text{for $x\in\mathbb{R}$}
    \end{align*}
    \newpage
    Hyperbolsk tangens er givet ved:
    \begin{align*}
    \tanh(x)=\frac{\sinh(x)}{\cosh(x)}=\frac{\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}}{\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}}=\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}} && \text{for $x\in\mathbb{R}$}
    \end{align*}
    Det ses, at $\tanh(x)=\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{f(x)+g(x)}=\frac{h_1(x)}{h_2(x)}$, hvor $h_1(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ og $h_2(x)=f(x)+g(x)$.
    \end{document}
```

Best regards

Comment: Don't use `\pagetotal` in `\cfoot`. Use lastpage to get the total number of pages http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=nofm.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Also, would you please please stop using ` \\ ` in the text! You do *NOT* need a forced line break at those places, they are new paragraps, ie add a blank line in the source. Yes, this will indent the new paragraphs as they should (to prevent confusion).

Comment: Another hint, `\tfrac` for simple fractions, forces it to become small. Those flying commas does not look particularly good either. Also, do do not really need to write `\frac{1}{2}\cdot e^x`, the `\cdot` is implied.

Comment: To clarify Ulrike's comment: `\pagetotal` is an internal parameter of TeX that *doesn't* refer to the total number of pages in the document.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a misuse of an internal command

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would you please make your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `\pagetotal` in  `\cfoot`. Use lastpage to get the total number of pages texfaq.org/FAQ-nofm .

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time I see error messages like this it is due to forgetting a mandatory argument (some length) to a command, sometimes due to a `{...}` or similar that gets misinterpreted. Check the documentation for the environments/commands used on the offending line (and nearby ones, or sometimes the one just closed) and make sure nothing is amiss.

[Yes, I know this isn't a solution to *this* particular problem, just posted for the benefit of any lost soul straying here because of the subject.]